# How to check in jQuery datatable the clicked row and column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Use case:
user clicks on a datatable cell. Depending on the row and column of that cell certain action should be executed.

How can I check whether that doesn't click on a certain column and if he does not click on that column, then I would retrieve information from the row he clicked on and allow him to execute an action based on that information.

I did it like this and it works:

```
  var validColumn = false;
  $('#fooTable tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    validColumn = $('#fooTable').DataTable().cell(this).index().column !== 5;
  });
  $('#fooTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    if (validColumn) {
       //do stuff
    }
  });
```

But I feel there is a more elegant approach.

Comment: Show your html to help!

Answer (score 1):

First set an aria to the td to identify the position, something like
Table wiht 6  columns so

```
<tr aria-number="1">
    <td aria-number="1">
    <td aria-number="2">
    <td aria-number="3">
    <td aria-number="4">
    <td aria-number="5">
    <td aria-number="6">
</tr>
```

Same for tr, think is easy way to do

Use jQuery function .parent(), sending $(this), so.

```
var td = $(this).parent();//If the item clicked is something inside of td
var tr = $(this).parent().parent();//To select the tr where was clicked
```

And call the aria with

```
if(td.attr('aria-number') == 6){ //do something; }
```